# Find maximum element in Clojure sorted-set

Tags: clojure

I am looking for an idiomatic, O(1), way to extract the maximum element of a `sorted-set` of integers, in Clojure. Do I have to cast the set into a seq?

Comment: definitely not seq, access to `last` in a seq is O(n)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Clojure's built-in sorted sets, this is O(log n):

```
(first (rseq the-set))
```

With [data.avl](https://github.com/clojure/data.avl) sets, the above also works, and you can also use `nth` to access elements by rank in O(log n) time:

```
(nth the-set (dec (count the-set)))
```

None of these data structures offers O(1) access to extreme elements, but you could certainly use `[the-set max-element]` bundles (possibly represented as records for cleaner manipulation) with a custom API if you expect to perform frequent repeated accesses to the maximum element.

If you only care about fast access to the maximum element and not about ordered traversals, you could actually use the bundle approach with "unsorted" sets – either built-in hash sets or [data.int-map](https://github.com/clojure/data.int-map) sets. That's not useful for repeated `disj` of maximum elements, of course, only for maintaining upper bound information for a fundamentally unsorted set (unless you keep a stack of max elements in the bundle, at which point it definitely makes sense to simply use sorted sets and get all relevant operations for free).

Comment: No worries. NB. for some reason I originally mentioned data.int-map in the first paragraph, but data.int-map sets are not actually sorted and do not guarantee that `(comp first rseq)` will access the maximum element – I've fixed that part of the answer now. Those sets are very fast and may be ok for you under the "bundle" approach, however – see the newly added, correct mention of data.int-map in the final paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

If you take into account the construction of the set, `(into #{} my-coll)` & `(max my-set)` is faster, than `(into (sorted-seq) my-coll)` & `(last my-sorted-set)`.